# Tracking window.onerror seems to show that lots of users have problems with one or more scripts not loading?

Tags: javascript

I've started tracking client-side JS errors on my website.  I attach a handler to window.onerror which fires of an ajax request to a php page that then logs the error.

It was useful initially, throwing up a couple of bugs that I've never noticed myself.

But now I get an error every few minutes all day every day, pretty much always along the lines of one of these three (there's others, but these are the biggies):

```
1: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
2: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
3: Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

(`_` is a lazy helper function I've always used to avoid typing `document.getElementById` all the time)

The first one comes from pages where I'm including google maps JS, like so:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEYHERE"></script>
<script src="/js/mystuff.js"></script>
```

My local file, maps.js refers to `google`, and sometimes `google` doesn't exist, presumably because the request to `maps.googleapis.com` has timed out, or because it's blocked for some reason.

The second one is odder, as I have this setup:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https://blahblahblah.com/js/jquery.3.3.1.min.js">\x3C/script>');</script>
<script src="/js/mystuff.js"></script>
```

So if the CDN is down for whatever reason, the site SHOULD serve up my local copy of jQuery instead.  So to get the `$ is not defined` error, jQuery needs to have failed to have loaded twice!

The third one is odd as well, as `_` is defined in another JS file on my own server:

```
<script src="/js/common.js"></script>
<script src="/js/mystuff.js"></script>
```

So to get that error the site has managed to load the second file, but not the first one.

Is all of the above perfectly normal, and "just one of those things"?  What can we do to improve the situation?!

Comment: I'd also track the browsers. Maybe it's a browser that lacks support, or you code is having issues functioning on those browsers. If you track the browser you can run some tests locally to find out - or with browser testing services. I find [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) useful for this sort of logging in production.

Comment: You might want to check if either Content Security Policy or some form of privacy plugin are blocking your scripts

Comment: I did look briefly at Sentry, but the price put me off.  I may end up using it anyway, if trying to roll it myself proves fruitless.

Comment: They have a free version that allows you to log 10,000 requests a month I believe. Their pricing page lists what's available in the free version.

Comment: But only for a single user it says, i.e. me (development), I assumed?  If I'm mistaken and I can roll it out on the public-facing site I'll definitely give it a try. Maybe single user meant I only get one log-in for the sentry website.

Comment: FWIW though @BugHunterUK, there's absolutely nothing fancy/clever about my javascript code e.g. in the file where _ is defined, so it definitely feels like a sporadic network/loading problem that maybe will never be fixable?

Comment: Possibly. I've noticed the same things myself. A lot of the time I notice users are on older phones. Like some older Samsung's don't support react. In those cases there's nothing you can do unless you want to support them.